# Default notification return false in Google Calendar Api

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-calendar-api

**EDITED:**

I created an "**all day**" event (EventX) using Google Calendar App with default notifications,

When I fetch the event details in my app, the notification of EventX shows as

```
   "reminders": {
       "useDefault": false
   },
```

If I created an event with no reminders still the API shows. the same response

```
   "reminders": {
       "useDefault": false
   },
```

I created another event in Google's Calendar app. (EventY)
It had default notification as (On the day at 9AM).
I added couple more notifications. But the default notification
is not shown.

[image]
**Event in Google Calendar App**

There are 4 notifications for the events where On the day 9AM is default notification.

But when I fetch from API.. the json is like this

```
"reminders": {
  "useDefault": false,
  "overrides": [
   {
    "method": "popup",
    "minutes": 840      // The day before at 10AM
   },
   {
    "method": "popup",
    "minutes": 900      // The day before at 9AM
   },
   {
    "method": "popup",
    "minutes": 2340     // 2 day before at 9AM
   }
  ]
 },
```

The notifications work right for normal events (**non allDay events**).

Is this how its supposed to work or is this some bug?

Comment: Clarifying, you say: All Day events with reminders set to default, fetched details show:  ```"useDefault": false``` AND Hourly events with reminders set to default, fetched details show: ```"useDefault": true```, is that right? Could you also share from the API Explorer how are you inserting this and the results you get? I ask because I just tested and I do get: ```"useDefault": false,
    "overrides": [
     {
      "method": "popup",
      "minutes": 10``` for all day events.

Comment: I've edited my question to sound it bit more clearer.. I just checked a few more times after I posted this question.. :D

Answer (score 0):

From what I've researched I think **same day notification** should be implemented specific to our app and should not depend on Calendar API...

I implemented all day notification using **extendedProperties**.. and explicitly added key for same day notification.

Since, I cant use **same day notification** created in Google Calendar app, this way even Google Calendar can't use **same day notification** which I've implemented ;p...

I'm not marking this answer as right, hoping someone will answer right someday.. :D